# How to add +1 in firebase when img is click android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code. I have two android phones and two accounts, but when I click the `image1`, which is `pres1` and click on the other phone, it doesn't stack. It remains 1 in the firebase.

Could anyone show me how to do it properly?

Thank you

```
private ImageView pres1, pres2;

long count;

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VoteResults");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vote_now);

    pres1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vote_president1);
    pres2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vote_president2);

    pres2.setOnClickListener(this);
    pres1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view.getId() == R.id.vote_president1){

        final DatabaseReference mCounterRef = mRootRef.child("VotePresident");
        mCounterRef.setValue(++count);
        startActivity(new Intent(VoteNow.this,VicePresInternal.class));
        finish();
    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.vote_president2) {
        final DatabaseReference mCounterRef = mRootRef.child("VotePresident2");
        mCounterRef.setValue(++count);
        startActivity(new Intent(VoteNow.this, VicePresInternal.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you are working with firebase, the best way is to working with POJO models - Plain Old Java Object.

So, you have to create POJO class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
    public class President {

        public String uuid = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";
        public int voteCount = 0;

        public Post() {
            // Default constructor required for calls to 
            DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
        }

        public President(String uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }
    }
```

And then you can work with DataSnapshot class, of course if added addValueEventListener() to you database reference

```
ValueEventListener voteListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        President president = dataSnapshot.getValue(President.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mRootRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Comment: thanks but i coudnt really understand it..btw im new to java and firebase and android studio sorry ..so did you mean i have to create another java class President? or ill just put it below my codes? thank you

Comment: Nothing meters, we all were novices)) you can take and put this pojo in your project. But add fields from your firebase dB structure. You can export Json from firebase and with service http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ convert to Java class